# How to do xpath "and" / condition query correctly?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am trying to set a checkmark on the prime option on amazon.fr.

Here is the link (the prime option is on the left): https://www.amazon.fr/gp/browse.html?node=2036893031.

Here is an image that shows the field I want to checkmark: https://ibb.co/ZY3mK3Z

I have it almost working. But it does not work for all amazon-categories, that's why I added the "and"-operator. Here is my xpath-query:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(category_url)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="leftNav"]/h4[text()="%s"]/following-sibling::ul//input[contains(@name, "s-ref-checkbox-")] and //*[@id="leftNav"]/h4[text()="%s"]/following-sibling::ul//input[contains(@name, "s-ref-checkbox-")]//i[contains(@class, "icon-prime")]' % ("Option d'expédition", "Option d'expédition"))
driver.click()
```

How can I format my query correctly? Is the and operator even necessary? I get the following error message:

> TypeError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The result is
> not a node set, and therefore cannot be converted to the desired type.

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: The image was not code, but showed the part of the website to be scraped.

Comment: I saw... but [HTML is considered code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362515/is-this-formatting-overuse/362602#comment552544_362523) also and should be included in the question itself as text and properly formatted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are trying to click without passing the WebElement.
You can find the checkbox based on the position of Prime label next to it.

Try the following xpath,

```
myprime = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(@class,'icon-prime a-icon-small s-ref-text-link')]/parent::span/parent::label/input")
myprime.click();
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now it works! I've been trying for a few hours to get it right.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried the XPath below and it uniquely located the element

```
//label[.//i[contains(@class, 'a-icon-prime')]]/input
^ find a LABEL tag
       ^ that has a child I tag
            ^ that contains the class 'a-icon-prime' (indicating the prime logo)
                                               ^ then find an INPUT under the LABEL
```

Answer (score 0):

The minimal working [XPath locator](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp) would be:

```
//i[contains(@class,'small') and contains(@class,'prime')]
```

For better robustness and reliability I would recommend wrapping it into an [Explicit Wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) like:

```
prime = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//i[contains(@class,'small') and contains(@class,'prime')]")))
prime.click()
```

More information: [How to use Selenium to test web applications using AJAX technology](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/)